# non system disk error when booting after attempting ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

i tried to install ubuntu server 16.04 on my hp laptop elitebook 6930p and i was at the partitioning stage. the ui was confusing for me so i fiddled with it a bit but i never actually completed the partitioning step. i decided to abort the installation and create the partition inside windows. i shut down the laptop and when i boot, it comes up with  a blank screen with flashing underscore at the top left. i used a windows 10 recovery disk to fix bootloader, nothing. i looked it up and went to cmd to put in the commands, Bootrec.exe /FixMbr, Bootrec.exe /FixBoot, Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd. When i did the third one it said there was 0 windows installations in the disk. now when i boot up it says non system disk or disk error. not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you messed up your Windows partitions.

What to do depends on what you need:

Do you need data on those partitions? If yes, then get in touch with someone or a company that can help recover the data.

Do you need Windows on the laptop and have a back-up of the data? If yes, then install Windows using your Windows media and restore your data.

Do you NOT need Windows on the laptop and have a back-up of the data? If yes, then you can use Ubuntu install media to install using the entire drive.

Do you want to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu? Then you'll need to re-install Windows first, then install Ubuntu second.

I recommend using the desktop version of Ubuntu on a bare metal laptop. It would be better to deploy Ubuntu server in a virtual machine on Windows if all you want is Ubuntu server.